# What is the Scala syntax for calling a function with variadic arguments but with named arguments?

Tags: scala, variadic-functions, keyword-argument

Say I have a function

```
def f(a:Int = 0, b:String = "", c:Float=0.0, foos: Foo*) { ... }
```

Notice the use of default arguments for some parameters. Typically, to make use of default values, you invoke a function with named parameters like so:

```
val foo = Foo("Foo!")
f(foos = foo)
```

This syntax works because **I'm only invoking the method with one `foo`**. However, if I have two or more

```
val foo1 = Foo("Foo!")
val foo2 = Foo("Bar!")
f(foos = ...)
```

it's not so obvious what should be fed in here. `Seq(foo1,foo2)` and `Seq(foo1,foo2):_*` do not type check.

What's more, how can I call it with **no** `foo`s?

```
// All out of foos!
f(foos = ...)
```

For this case, calling the function with empty parentheses (`f()`) does not work.

Thanks!

Comment: what version of scala are you using? With 2.9.2 attempting to define f in the REPL gives me a "<console>:9: error: a parameter section with a `*'-parameter is not allowed to have default arguments"

Comment: I'm seeing this on 2.9.2 as well. However, the actual code I'm compiling is running 2.9.1, where apparently that is legal.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Given the Scala 2.9 limitations that Paolo mentioned, you can still use currying to divide the parameters in different sections, one which uses named parameters with default arguments, and one for varargs (or multiple curried argument sections if you want more than one vararg parameter). Regarding readability the result is imho almost better than using named arguments only:

```
f(b="something")()
f(c=3.14)(foo1, foo2)
```

Answer (score 8):

For the default parameters, see my comment to your question. For how to call the variadic part with a named argument, see below (scala 2.9.2):

```
scala> case class Foo(a:Int)
defined class Foo

scala> def f(a:Int, foos: Foo*) = foos.length
f: (a: Int, foos: Foo*)Int

scala> f(a=2, foos=Foo(2))
res0: Int = 1

// I'm not sure if this is cheating...
// am I just naming the first of the two variadic arguments?
scala> f(a=2, foos=Foo(2),Foo(3))
res1: Int = 2

//anyway you can do ....
scala> f(a=2, foos=Seq(Foo(1), Foo(2)):_*)
res2: Int = 2

// with no foos...
scala> f(a=2, foos=Nil:_*)
res3: Int = 0
```

Comment: Thank you, that makes it quite clear. I'm going to accept your answer because it corresponds more closely to the question, though in terms of practicality I think I'll adopt bluenote10's approach.

Comment: @fatu I know that my answer is [technically correct](www.deadprogrammer.com/technically-correct/)... I also think bluenote10's approach is better and a more useful brand of correct. You can still un-accept mine and accept his answer.